# If a base class has private data members that are modified in a member function, how does a derived class use that function?

Tags: c++, class, object, private

I'm working on a project to learn about object oriented programming. From what I understand, when a class is derived from a base class, it can access all of the public member functions of the base class. In C++ a public inheritance means that private members cannot be accessed. So what happens when a private member function is modified in a base class?

I have tried building some test programs to see what happens, but I'm still extremely confused. I also tried looking online to see if I can find any answers, but I didn't really find any.

```
class Base 
{
    private:
        int length;
    public 
        void increaseLengthByOne();
};

void Base::increaseLengthByOne()
{
    this->length++;
}

class Derived : public Base 
{
    private:
        int dLength;
    public: 
        void newFunction();
};

void Derived::newFunction()
{
    printf("New function working");
    increaseLengthByOne();
}
```

From what I understand, dLength won't be changed and Length can't be changed. What does the increaseLengthByOne function do then? And how would I make it so the increaseLength function can increase dLength?

Comment: tip: include some `cout`s to verify your assumptions. Is `increaseLengthByOne()` really no able to modify `length` when called from the derived?

Comment: surely, this must have a dupe.

Comment: Your data attributes (length and dLength) are un-initialized - undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

> From what I understand, [...] Length can't be changed.

You've misunderstood. A member being private does not imply that it cannot be changed.

> What does the increaseLengthByOne function do then?

It increases the member `length`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not because it's not visible that it doesn't exist or cannot access it. The method will be able to access the member variable because it was declared as being able to access it.

That's the principle of visibility for traditional method calls as well, such a method can access private or protected member of the class, even if the caller code cannot.

Answer (score 0):

> How does a derived class use that function?

When the Base function is public or protected, the derived class function can simply invoke the Base function.

When the Base function is private, the derived class function can not directly invoke it.

Below I have lightly touched your code to initialize, and demonstrate  derive class function invocation of Base functions.

Notes:

- Remember to initialize your data attributes --- I prefer initialization list of ctor.
- use cout to show what is happening, these are easily removed for submittal
- learn to use gdb

---

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::endl;  // feature requires -std=c++17


class Base
{
private:
   int length;

public:
   Base(int lInit = 0) : length(lInit)  // init length
      { cout << "\n  length init: " << length << endl; }

   void increaseLengthByOne();
};

void Base::increaseLengthByOne()
{
   length++;   // this->length++;
   cout <<  "\n  length++ : " << length;
}

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
   int dLength;

public:
   Derived() : Base(1), dLength(0)  // init Base and dLength
      { cout << "\n  dLength init: " << dLength << endl; }

   void newFunction(int d);
};

void Derived::newFunction(int d)
{
   cout << "\n  Derived::newFunction(int)";
   cout << "\n  dLength a: " << dLength;
   dLength = d;
   cout << "\n  dLength b: " << dLength;
   increaseLengthByOne();
   cout << "\n  dLength c: " << dLength;
}


class T989_t
{
public:
   int operator()() { return exec(); } // functor entry

private: // methods
   int exec()
      {
         Derived d;
         d.newFunction(5);    
         return 0;
      }
}; // class T98_t

int main(int , char** ) { return T989_t()(); } // invoke functor
```

Output:

```
  length init: 1

  dLength init: 0

  Derived::newFunction(int)
  dLength a: 0
  dLength b: 5
  length++ : 2
  dLength c: 5
```

Answer (score 0):

A member that is private won't be accessible outside the class.But You can always write wrapper or helper function to give its access outside the world.This is happening in your case.So the value of length would increase.

Answer (score 0):

> From what I understand, ... Length can't be changed.

length can't be changed directly outside `Base` class since it is a private member of `Base` class, however you can change it using public member function of `Base` class.

> What does the `increaseLengthByOne` function do then?

Derived class can access Base class public/protected members as such when you call `increaseLengthByOne`  in derived class it executes `Base` class function `increaseLengthByOne` which increases length.

> how would I make it so the `increaseLength` function can increase `dLength`?

There are 2 ways of doing this
1) Just add `dLength++` to your function `newFunction()` i.e

```
void Derived::newFunction()
{
    std::cout << "New function working";
    dLength++;
    increaseLengthByOne();
}
```

2) In case you want to keep function name `increaseLengthByOne` same then you can override it in derived class  i.e

```
class Derived : public Base 
{
   private:
    int dLength;
   public: 
    void newFunction();
    void increaseLengthByOne();  //this overrides Base class function
};

void Derived::increaseLengthByOne()
{
    dLength++;
    Base::increaseLengthByOne();   //this increases length;
}
```